# Primary key string e² == e2

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

**Edit** i know this is a bad table/primary key :) but my main goal is to solve that mysql thinks that Franz2 and Franz² are the "same"

I have a mysql database and play a litte bit around.

I have a table with the "name" and "age". (Name is the primary key (varchar))

Now i want add via sql 2 rows:

"Franz2", 2

"Franz²", 3

but i get an error that Franz2 it is already imported.
I already bumped my mysql version and tried utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci and utf8mb5_0900_ai_ci.
With this settings, other edge cases start to work but not this specific.

I dont really have the need to use it, but i wanna understand it and maybe fix it.

Unfortunately i found a lot about other problems that could be solve with another collation but nothing about my problem.
Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Names should never be used as a primary key. If your system considers names as unique you should use `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` in your `name` field and create the appropriate primary key.

Comment: yes i know that names never should be primary key :)  but i want to understand it anyway how i could solve that mysql think that Franz2 and Franz² are the same. I thought that this is a collation problem .... but the newer ones only solve other matches

Comment: Have you tried utf8mb5_0900_as_cs if it exists?

Comment: Short answer: No. This seems eg ms to be a data sanitisation error. If the really are the same, then ² should be converted to 2 on input.

Comment: @EricWong i will give it a try when i am back home .... Bohemian: it should NOT be the same but mysql say that it cannot insert the second value because the primary key already exists.

Comment: Please show your insert statements and create table DDL statement.

Comment: @EricWong: utf8mb4_0900_as_cs works ! Thank you... if you want post it as answer i will accept it. Thank you

Comment: Little bit late to the game, nvm. But just so you know, _ai_ci and "accent insensitive case insensitive", if I have to make a guess which collation will treat them as different, granted choosing "sensitive" ones is of higher chance :DDDD

Comment: @EricWong yeah you are right. After your solution works i read more about this and thought the same :D :D (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a collation where the two characters are treated as equal, then use that collation.

```
mysql> select 'Franz2' = 'Franz²' collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 'Franz2' = 'Franz²' collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               1 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'Franz2' = 'Franz²' collate utf8mb4_general_ci;
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 'Franz2' = 'Franz²' collate utf8mb4_general_ci  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               0 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

If you can't find a collation where the characters you want are defined as the same, then you may be able to [develop your own custom collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation.html). This would not be a task for the faint of heart.